# Using regex to parse multiline string

Tags: python, regex

This is the full string that I want to parse:

```
Response
--------
{
  Return Code: 1
  Key        : <None>
  Files      : [
    {
      Return Code: 0
      Data       : 'Value' is 1
'Value' is two
This is third line of output
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is how I want the parsed text to look like:

```
'Value' is 1
'Value' is two
This is third line of output
```

I've tried messing with `re.findall()` but I cannot get exactly what I want.
This is a python script which trys to parse using regex ..

```
import subprocess,re
output = subprocess.check_output(['staf', 'server.com', 'PROCESS', 'START', 'SHELL', 'COMMAND', "'uname'", 'WAIT', 'RETURNSTDOUT', 'STDERRTOSTDOUT'])
result = re.findall(r'Data\s+:\s+(.*)', output, re.DOTALL)[0]
print result
```

Output of script ..

```
[root@server ~]# python test.py 
''uname'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you want the three lines after `Data:`, you can do something like this, capturing the three lines into Group 1:

```
match = re.search(r"Data\s*:\s*((?:[^\n]*[\r\n]+){3})", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
```

**Option 2**

If you want all the lines after `Data:` before the first line that has a `}`, change the regex to :

```
Data\s*:\s*((?:[^\n]*(?:[\r\n]+(?!\s*}))?)+)
```

Comment: It will not always be only 3 lines, it can be N number of lines

Comment: And you know you got all the lines because of the `}`, or do you want to specify N lines in the regex? (If so, as I'm sure you realize, change the `3` with `5` or whatever)

Comment: @bobbyrne01 See Option 2 I just added to get all the lines before the first `}` line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following regex, you'll find the three strings you want.

Notice that this depends heavily on how the response is formatted.

```
>>> import re
>>> response = """
Response
--------
{
  Return Code: 1
  Key        : <None>
  Files      : [
    {
      Return Code: 0
      Data       : 'Value' is 1
'Value' is two
This is third line of output
    }
  ]
}"""
>>> re.findall(r"('Value'.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n.*}",response)
[("'Value' is 1", "'Value' is two", 'This is third line of output')]
```

You could also include the newline characters in the groups like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r"('Value'.*\n)(.*\n)(.*\n).*}",response)
[("'Value' is 1\n", "'Value' is two\n", 'This is third line of output\n')]
```

Depends on how you want to process this afterward.

**UPDATE**

How about this?

```
>>> re.findall(r"Data\s*:\s*(.*?)}",response,re.DOTALL)
["'Value' is 1\n'Value' is two\nThis is third line of output\n    "]
```

This will find everything from the first 'Value' up untill the first '}'.